# scala eval function in string form

Tags: scala, eval, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to define a DSL that will dictate how to parse CSVs. I would like to define simple functions to transform values as the values are being extracted from CSV. The DSL will defined in a text file.

For example, if the CSV looks like this:

```
id,name,amt
1,John Smith,$10.00
2,Bob Uncle,$20.00
```

I would like to *define* the following function (and please note that I would like to be able to execute arbitrary code) on the *amt* column

`(x: String) => x.replace("$", "")`

Is there a way to evaluate the function above and execute it for each of the *amt* values?

Comment: So your question is how to extract amt only?

Comment: Please can you check URl https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for enhance quality.

Answer (score 2):

First, please consider that there's probably a better way to do this. For one thing, it seems concerning that your external DSL contains Scala code. Does this really need to be a DSL?

That said, it's possible to evaluate arbitrary Scala using [ToolBox](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala-compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBox.html):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val code = """(x: String) => x.replace("$", "")"""
val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val func = toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(code)).asInstanceOf[String => String]
println(func("$10.50")) // prints "10.50"
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian McCutchon I agree that there probably is a better way to do this, but I plan on using this as a building block for other things and to prove a concept. Thanks for your concern and help!